# Booting Centos Box via Vagrant requires login

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to boot a Centos box using Vagrant. However, it gets stuck requiring logging in via the console.

**Stuck**
[image]

**Console**
[image]

So as I understand it Vagrant cannot connect to bootstrap the instance because it cannot authenticate. I have tried adding

```
config.ssh.username = "vagrant"
config.ssh.password = "vagrant"
```

to the `Vagrantfile` but it makes no difference.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That's not a "GUI" so much as it is the console (which isn't ssh). Is the ssh server running at that point if you log in from the console?

Comment: @EtanReisner noted. I made that mistake because to get the console to show I had to enable `vb.gui = true`. I am not sure how to answer if the ssh server is running How would I check that?

Comment: What does `service sshd status` say? What about `ss -tlnp`?